# Optimization algorithm to find coinciding root and minimum

Tags: optimization

Are there any optimization algorithms aimed at finding a coinciding root and a (local) minimum of a multi-variable function `f`. Say it is known analytically that these should coincide for the function.

---

I am interested in any such algorithm but more specifically for the case where `f` is continuous, at least twice differentiable and very expensive to compute (so internal costs for the algorithm can be neglected, only function calls matter). What would you use if the gradient could be computed for free? What if the Hessian can also be computed for free? What if the root and the minimum only coincide approximately, i.e. the minimum $f(x_c)\in $ $[-\epsilon,\epsilon]$ for some small epsilon.

Comment: What is the advantage of it being a root of the function? If it coincides with a local minimum it means that a perturbation would lead to infinite crosses with zero or non in the vicinity. Why not using an optimization algorithm?

Comment: @nico, There is a clear advantage in knowing you are searching for a root as well. Say you would like to use gradient descent. Normally you don't know what step length to take. Now at least some idea of the appropriate step length comes from solving for the root. Similarly for something using a quadratic model you can solve for both the minimum and the root (if you have a full Hessian this would be overconstrained but if you use some kind of BFGS updating where the Hessian is not fully determined the extra equations can help).

Comment: Of course we can trivially rephrase this question as searching for a minimum if the value at the minimum is already known. Perhaps that will make things more clear and ring some bells for some people instead.

Comment: You could do something like a line search for the step size.

Comment: @nico, right the point is that you don't have to (or rather you have a much better initial guess) when you know you are also looking for a root. Anyway it is really simple you have more equations so you know more about the function so you expect optimization to be faster. Perhaps this is too much of a niche to have good standard algorithms but it does not sound too obscure a problem so someone must have thought about this already.

Comment: Is it 1D? Is the second derivative finite (nonzero) at the root? Or that is not known?

Comment: This can be formulated as a standard constrained optimization problem in which $f(x_c) = 0$ or $f(x_c) \in [-\epsilon,\epsilon]$ is included in the constraints. Whether incorporation of such constraint makes it easier or harder to solve is another matter. Presuming $f$ is nonlinear, the added constraint(s) will be non-convex.

Comment: @MarkL.Stone i don't think you can reformulate it that way. OP wants points that are both local minima and roots. If you add it as a constraint, it would only be valid for points where the multiplier of the constraint is zero.